# Does jquery 1.4 completely compatible with jquery 1.32?

Tags: jquery

Does jquery 1.4 completely compatible with jquery 1.32 ? I have lots of codes written in jquery 1.32, I don't know whether upgrading to 1.4 will affect my legacy codes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no it isn't. You will need to update the jquery-ui library and some functions got deleted or changed.

Here is a list that gives you the compatibility changes:
[Compatibility list](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards)

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine, the move to 1.4.2 from 1.3.2 is a lot easier than the move from 1.2.6 to 1.3.2.

As always you need to test though.